# Declare a variable or constant that conforms to a protocol in Swift

Tags: protocols, swift

In Swift how do you declare a variable (or constant) that conforms to a protocol?

I've tried

```
let whatever: protocol <myProtocol>
```

and

```
let whatever: myProtocol
```

But when setting it I get the error

```
Cannot convert the expression's type '()' to type 'myProtocol'
```

Comment: Where are you writing this? Is it in a type definition?

Comment: Seems like you've left something out: what exactly are you doing when you're 'setting it'?

Comment: @Chuck yes it is in the class definition for a table VC (in Obj-C terms I want a strong reference to a property that conforms to a protocol, and I want to initialize it in my init)

Comment: @Yawar I'm doing `self.whatever = ObjectThatConformsToMyProtocol()`

Comment: The error message suggests that `ObjectThatConformsToMyProtocol()` doesn't in fact conform to the protocol :-) Check that expression to figure out how to make it conform....

Answer (score 2):

There is no such necessary to do such thing, because when you declare the type of your variable (or constant), it should be known if it is conforming a protocol or not. But in case sometimes you are using legacy objc id, you may get an `AnyObject`. In that situation, you can just do a downcast to convert it as a protocol type and use it.

```
let whatever: AnyObject = someObj
let conformProtocol = whatever as myProtocol

conformProtocol.callMethod()
```

Or you may want to use `as?` for a safer converting.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Declarations.html):

> Protocols are named types, and thus they can appear in all the same places in your code as other named types, as discussed in Protocols as Types. However, **you can’t construct an instance of a protocol, because protocols do not actually provide the implementations for the requirements they specify.**

Comment: That's fine, but the question doesn't suggest that's happening here. Your point would be valid if the code was something like `let whatever = MyProtocol()`--but it's not.